# Delay onCreateView() of a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My code fetches data via loader from the internet, which gets passed into the fragment via bundle and then should be displayed in the fragment's view.

Problem is, that the fragement's *onCreateView()*-Method get's called, before my data is ready, so the bundles arguments are null.

How can I postpone that process, so the data is ready when *onCreateView()* gets called?

I try and post just the code necessary, tell me if you need some more.

PS. Originally, I tried to pass the whole *List NewsEntry* to the fragment, but that failed horribly, so I had to convert it to a StringArray in order to put it in the bundle. If you can tell me a better way to pass this list to the fragment, I'd be very grateful too :)

Thank you

**SpinnerActivity.java**

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(
        AdapterView<?> parent, 
        View view, 
        int position, 
        long id
) {
    mQuery = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    buildQuery();
    loaderManager.destroyLoader(0);
    Loader loader = loaderManager.initLoader(0, null, this);
}

public void onLoadFinished(
        Loader<List<NewsEntry>> loader, 
        List<NewsEntry> fetchedNewsEntries
) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    ArrayList<String> newsEntriesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    ...

    bundle.putStringArrayList("newsEntries", newsEntriesArrayList);
    NewsEntryFragment fragment = new NewsEntryFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
}
```

**NewsEntryFragment.java**

```
public NewsEntryFragment() {}

public static void newInstance(int columnCount) {

    NewsEntryFragment fragment = new NewsEntryFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mColumnCount = getArguments().getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(
        @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, 
        ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState
) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_newsentry_list, container, false);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        ArrayList<String> newsEntriesStringArrayList = 
            new ArrayList<>(
                Objects.requireNonNull( 
                    getArguments().getStringArrayList( "newsEntries" ) 
                )
            )
        ;

        ArrayList<NewsEntry> newsEntriesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < newsEntriesStringArrayList.size(); i++){
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String sArray[];
                sArray = newsEntriesStringArrayList.get(i).split(",");
                NewsEntry newsEntry = 
                    new NewsEntry(
                        sArray[0], 
                        sArray[1], 
                        sArray[2], 
                        sArray[3], 
                        sArray[4]
                    )
                ;

                newsEntriesArrayList.add(newsEntry);
            }
    }


    // Set the adapter
    if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
        Context context = view.getContext();
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
        if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        } else {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
        }
        recyclerView
            .setAdapter(
                new MyNewsEntryRecyclerViewAdapter(
                    mNewsEntries, 
                    mListener
                )
            )
        ;
    }
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnListFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnListFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    ...

    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_fragment_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <fragment android:name="com.example.bjonic.guardiannewsfeed.NewsEntryFragment"
        android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: May i suggest using AsyncTasks to load your data and just display a loading symbol untill the data is ready?

Comment: İnitialize the recyclerview with empty array and when your data fetched call notifyDataSetChanged on adapter

Comment: I would not use the bundle to communicate data between your activity and the fragment. Define an interface inside the activity and let the fragment implement the interface

Answer (score 0):

Shift the code to get data from onCreateView() to onViewCreated()
and in order to send the arrayList you need to make NewsEntry class Parcelable and then you can do the following -

```
    args.putParcelableArrayList("list", yourList);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sadly, that didn't help. 

The problem is, that the Fragment views get created, before even the loader does. I need to change that.

Answer (score 0):

Make an interface callback in your fragment and invoke the interface once the task is completed

Comment: So I now implemented that interface and I do get the data from the internet query within my fragment, but it still triggers the interface before my data is ready.

Comment: Just do your task in background thread like async or service..after completing the task invoke the interface at the next line of your task execution code